# Set proxy for selenium chrome driver in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, browsermob

Browsermob proxy:-

```
https://github.com/jarib/browsermob-proxy-rb
```

I can able to create and set proxy for firefox profile but not on chrome.

I don't know which options i have to use for chrome to set proxy.

Am using the following code:-

For firefox:-

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/path/to/downloads/browsermob-proxy/bin/browsermob-proxy") #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Server:0x000001022c6ea8 ...>
server.start

proxy = server.create_proxy #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Client:0x0000010224bdc0 ...>

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new #=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x000001022bf748 ...>
profile.proxy = proxy.selenium_proxy

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile

proxy.new_har "google"
driver.get "http://google.com"

har = proxy.har #=> #<HAR::Archive:0x-27066c42d7e75fa6>
har.entries.first.request.url #=> "http://google.com"
har.save_to "/tmp/google.har"

proxy.close
driver.quit
```

For chrome:-

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/path/to/downloads/browsermob-proxy/bin/browsermob-proxy") #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Server:0x000001022c6ea8 ...>
server.start

proxy = server.create_proxy #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Client:0x0000010224bdc0 ...>

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new #=>
profile.proxy = proxy.selenium_proxy

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :prefs => profile

proxy.new_har "google"
driver.get "http://google.com"

har = proxy.har #=> #<HAR::Archive:0x-27066c42d7e75fa6>
har.entries.first.request.url #=> "http://google.com"
har.save_to "/tmp/google.har"

proxy.close
driver.quit
```

In chrome, errors throws on the following line

```
profile.proxy = proxy.selenium_proxy
```

Error:-   NoMethodError: undefined method `proxy=' for #

How to set proxy on chrome driver profile ?

Answer (score 2):

Hey not sure if resolve this issue already, I faced same problem but finally got that work by using this code:

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/path/to/downloads/browsermob-proxy/bin/browsermob-proxy") #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Server:0x000001022c6ea8 ...>
server.start

proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(:http => @proxy.selenium_proxy.http)
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(:proxy => proxy)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Then you can save the har file using  `har= proxy.har`

By using this basically you avoiding to chromedriver to point to wrong port and localhost. Also this approach works also on IEdriver just change the caps to

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internetexplorer(:proxy => proxy)
```

Hope this approach helps :)

Comment: This is very confusing. Where does your @proxy come from. What does it contain. How do I build it.